# Regular expression to extract from URI

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to extract from two types of URIs

```
http://example.com/path/to/page/?filter
http://example.com/path/to/?filter
```

Basically, in both cases I need to somehow isolate and return

```
/path/to
```

and

```
?filter
```

That is, both `/path/to` and `filter` is arbitrary. So I suppose I need **2** regular expressions for this?  I am doing this in PHP but if someone could help me out with the regular expressions I can figure out the rest.  Thanks for your time :)

EDIT: So just want to clearify, if for example

```
http://example.com/help/faq/?sort=latest
```

I want to get `/help/faq` and `?sort=latest`

Another example

```
http://example.com/site/users/all/page/?filter=none&status=2
```

I want to get `/site/users/all` and `?filter=none&status=2`. Note that I do not want to get the `page`!

Comment: do you only want to return the first two directories ("path" and "to")? and what else can "?filter" be? can it also be "?foo" or "?foo=123" or "?foo=bar"?

Comment: Does the second match always have to start with a question-mark?

Comment: What do you mean by you need to capture `/path/to`? That you need to capture the first two elements of the path?

Comment: Sorry should've been more clearer. `/path/to` can be anything like `/help/faq` or `/site/users/all` while `filter` are arguments like `order=desc&foo=bar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) might be easier and have fewer side-effects then regex:

```
$querystring = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY); 
$path = parse_url($var, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

You could then use explode on the path to get the first two segments:

```
$segments = explode("/", $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^http://[^/?#]+/([^/?#]+/[^/?#]+)[^?#]*\?([^#]*)
```

This will get you the first two URL path segments and query.

Answer (score 0):

not tested but:

```
^https?://[^ /]+[^ ?]+.*
```

which should match http and https url with or without path, the second argument should match until the ? (from the ?filter for instance) and the .* any char except the \n.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `explode()` instead (http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) ? The task seems simple enough for it. You would need 2 calls (one for the / and one for the ?) but it should be quite simple once you did that.